# Read and Save multiple images in a folder: Python

Tags: python, image, python-2.7

I am a beginner in python. I am trying to read all of the ascii files from one folder and after converting them into Image, I want all of them to be saved into a different folder in same directory. The code is running but I am not getting any output and no error is displayed.

Code without loop, for single image is working perfectly.

Please help.

```
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

path = r'D:\user\ASCII'
outpath = 'D:\user\ASCII\TIFF'

filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.asc") #read all files in the path mentioned

for x in filenames:
    myarray = np.loadtxt(x, skiprows=9)
    im = Image.fromarray(myarray)
    im.save(outpath + '/*.tif')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an asterisk in the `save()` function which makes no sense, it has nothing to match. It will not automatically substitute the `*` match from glob function. I think what you wanted to do something like this

```
src_fname, ext = os.path.splitext(x)  # split filename and extension
# construct output filename, basename to remove input directory
save_fname = os.path.join(outpath, os.path.basename(src_fname)+'.tif')
im.save(save_fname)
```

Remember to use `os.path` module functions instead of concatenating filenames with slashes as they handle edge cases correctly on every platform.

Comment: Thanks Ondřej for help. if we split the file name and extension then 'np.loadtext' would not work.

Comment: You split it after you use `np.loadtxt(x)`, that way the original `x` variable is a full valid file name.